# Signing and Verification from e-token Certificate

Tags: c#, token, sign, pki, verify

How can i sign and verify any message from the digital certificate stored in a token in C#?I have done encryption and decryption from e-token certificate.But not finding any solution for signing and verification. If any one know please reply because i have been trying for a long time..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pkcs11 DLL provided by eToken and write a wrapper over it using C#. You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791602/how-to-start-coding-in-c-sharp-for-etoken) This might not solve your problem but this could help you with it